# How to align buttons horizontally across multiple screen sizes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three buttons that I am trying to align horizontally across multiple screen sizes (Desktop, Laptop, Ipad, Iphone). They only way I been able to do this is to use media queries for the different screen sizes.  Is there another way to align the button horizontally?

Here is my code

```
    <div class="row" id="plans-row">
        <div class="col-md-4 individual-plans" style="background-color: #FDFDFD;">

                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-default emphasis btn-lg signupBtn">Choose Plan</button>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 individual-plans" style="background-color: #FAFAFA;">
                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-default emphasis btn-lg signupBtn" onclick="parent.location='/login?redirect=plan&openPlan=1'">Choose Plan</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 individual-plans" style="background-color: #FDFDFD;">
            <div class="offWhiteArea plan rounded-top-right rounded-bottom-right adjustable-col">
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-default emphasis btn-lg signupBtn" onclick="parent.location='/login?redirect=plan&openPlan=3'">Choose Plan</button>

                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Assuming bootstrap?  If so make your colums a third at the small size instead of the medium size.  col-xs-4.

Comment: that's not correct.  you can have mutliple columns at the smallest breakpoint in bootstrap.  Unless you have some other css overriding it's default behavior. There are tons of grid examples out there at the XS breakpoint showing multiple columns per row.

Comment: then i believe you just do `col-4`

Comment: I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Bootstrap 4, and you're defining your columns to be a third of the row of 12 columns at the medium breakpoint (`.col-md-4`) the columns are going to be full width (stacked) at sizes below medium.  If you want them to always be side by side, start out at the small breakpoint (`.col-4`).  Also you have some stray closing `</div>` tags in your code example which is also causing problems.

(If using Bootstrap 3, same issue however you'll want to use `.col-xs-4` to start at the smallest breakpoint)

**Documentation for Bootstrap 4 "All breakpoints":**

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#all-breakpoints

```
<div class="row" id="plans-row">
    <div class="col-4 individual-plans" style="background-color: #FDFDFD;">
         <button class="btn btn-success btn-default emphasis btn-lg signupBtn">Choose Plan</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 individual-plans" style="background-color: #FAFAFA;">
         <button class="btn btn-success btn-default emphasis btn-lg signupBtn" onclick="parent.location='/login?redirect=plan&openPlan=1'">Choose Plan</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 individual-plans" style="background-color: #FDFDFD;">
        <div class="offWhiteArea plan rounded-top-right rounded-bottom-right adjustable-col">
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-default emphasis btn-lg signupBtn" onclick="parent.location='/login?redirect=plan&openPlan=3'">Choose Plan</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use flex box, but combining that with a grid system that's already in use throughout your site could have bad side effects. If you add that to your row class as mentioned in another answer, you're doing that to all your rows which load that CSS.  Going the flexbox route is a great idea and an improvement but if you take that route, I would create an extended class or completely separate container for that use.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `display:flex;` on `.row` you will get horizontal buttons. By adding `justify-content: space-between;` you can get them evenly spaced. In this case, you don't need bootstrap's `col-md-4` classes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to many closing div-tags.
Remove the second and the forth and I think It should do the trick (if I understood your question right).